# Change value of a column based on whether string is in another column using R

Tags: r, regex, substring

I want to create a new column based on whether a string is present in a different column of the dataframe.

```
 name
  Jon
  Anne
Jobraith
  Knut
```

Becomes:

```
 name      dummy
  Jon        1
  Anne       0
Jobraith     1
  Knut       0
```

looking for something along the lines of:

`df$dummy <- ifelse('jo' in df$name, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`grepl( ... )`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) to check for the substring ...

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('Jon', 'Anne', 'Jobraith', 'Knut'))
df$dummy <- as.numeric(grepl('jo', df$name, ignore.case=T))
df

#       name dummy
# 1      Jon     1
# 2     Anne     0
# 3 Jobraith     1
# 4     Knut     0
```

Comment: Why would you use `ifelse` here? Why not just `as.numeric`?

Comment: ifelse is nice though because it's a bit more general in the case that 0,1 isn't wanted